# Aplicação on-line se comunicar com um computador local?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, front-end

Como faço para que uma aplicação web on-line se comunique com um computador local?

O objetivo é enviar dados para um computador local, e em principio pensei enviar utilizando Jquery/Ajax. Teria como fazer?

Caso não, quais outras formas poderiam ser feito?

---

Tenho uma aplicação rodando on-line em php e necessito que ela envie dados para um servidor local. O envio de dados acontece somente após o usuário da aplicação apertar o botão "salvar" na aplicação. Comunicação simples.  Não sei se consegui ser claro o suficiente.

---

Seria assim, a aplicação dorando on-line e a necessidade de uma cópia no servidor local

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]